# How to pass vector to a overloaded output stream that takes a custom object as an argument?

Tags: c++, object, vector, output

```
 class example{
 int n;
 vector <double> vec;

 example(const vector <double> &vec) : vec(vec){}

 void set_data(const vector<double> &v){vec = v;}
 const vector<double> &get_data() const {return vec;}

 };

ostream &operator<< (ostream &output, const sample &s){
  return output << "< " << s.get_data().size()  << " : " << //element1 << element2 << //elementN;
}
```

I am trying create a custom output stream for a class that creates vector objects. The
output should return the size (i.e. number of elements in vector) and the elements in the vector.

The problem now is when I create a new example class object it only creates a vector with one element.

For example when I create a object like 'sample s(vector  vec); it understandibly creates an object with one item. I have tried adding more arguments to the the constructor like a 'const vector  &vec(n), int n): vec(vec), n(n){}' but it still doesnt work. The compiler returns an error that says: 'expected ',' or '...' before '(' token.

Comment: The functions in the class have access to all the vector functions, but the class is not a vector itself, therefore you can't expect it to behave (or have the functions) of a vector.

Comment: You changed the question. Start a new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors have absolutely nothing to do with `vector`, streams, or access control. You're simply using invalid syntax to declare the `vec` member and constructor parameter.

**Edit to respond to updated question:**

> The problem now is when I create a new example class object it only creates a vector with one element.

That's a different question than your original one. You should open a new question.

> For example when I create a object like 'sample s(vector vec); it understandibly creates an object with one item.

No, this declares a function called `s` that takes a `vector` argument called `vec` and returns a `sample`. You seriously need to get the basic syntax of the language down.

Comment: Well, he also needs to do `s.get_data().size()` instead of `s.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer concrete, you constructor needs to be

```
 class example{
 // ...
 example(const vector<double> &vec_, int n_)
   : vec(vec_), n(n_)
 { }

 // ... 
};
```

This will initialize `vec` to be copy of the argument, which should be passed by reference to avoid superfluous copies.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```c++
vector<double> vec(n);
```

Can't appear inside the class body as a variable declaration. It should be initialized like this:

```c++
vector<double> vec = vector<double>(n); // copy-initialization
```

or using the member initializer list:

```c++
example(vector<double> vec const&) : vec(vec) { }
```

which will copy-construct it from another instance.